# How to get the URL of window.opener using Java Script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5

I have open a new window from another window. I need to get the parent (opener) windows url. Is there a way to get the window.opener url?

Answer (score 3):

`window.opener.location.href` is what you want. However, you can only read this if it's in the same domain as the window you are calling it from.

Answer (score 0):

It will be redirect to another page.

```
 window.location = "https://www.w3schools.com"
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.referrer` seems to do the trick

Some tests:

```js
if (window.opener) {
  console.log(
    window,
    window.opener,
    window.opener === window,
    document.referrer, // Works!
    // window.opener.location.href, // crashes
    // window.opener.location.toString(), // crashes
    // window.opener.document, // crashes
  )
}
```